# Vuejs how to pass component data from caller

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My main page renders a list of data coming from controller with `foreach`

```
@foreach ($sales as $sale)
    <button id="{{$sale->id}}" @click="editClicked({{$sale}})">
@endforeach
```

I have an `edit` component placed on the page like this, I display it modally via `showEditModal` conditional

```
<edit v-if="showEditModal" @hide="showEditModal=false"></edit>
```

The component in brief is declared in `Edit.vue`:

```
<template name="edit">
    ...
</template>
```

This is simply a standard form with input fields, bound via v-model to the `sale`.

Essentially it is an update form, I intend to load the data from the main page into each input field to be edited.

My app.js simply sets `showEditModal = true`, in order to display the edit form on top of the main page.

Basically i don't want to have to call controller via GET method on loading the modal since i already have the data in the main page as `$sale` object, so im just wondering how do I pass in the `$sale` to the Edit.vue component ?

I thought that in the `<edit>` component usage, it would need to bind the `sale` object, however I'm unsure how that would work since it comes from the foreach loop.

I do, also have the data in the app.js method as passed in via `@click="editClicked({{$sale}})"`, but again, i'm unsure how to use that to pass through ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you would want to pass the current `sale` item as a property to the edit modal. What I would do is add a data property to your main Vue called `selectedSale`.

```
data:{
  selectedSale: null
}
```

Then in your `editClicked` method, set `selectedSale`

```
methods:{
  editClicked(sale){
    this.selectedSale = sale
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally, pass it as a property.

```
<edit :sale="selectedSale" v-if="showEditModal" @hide="showEditModal=false"></edit>
```